# How to find a limit of this?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I'm trying to solve this problem,
$\lim_{x\to 0+}(\sin^2(4x))^{\sin^{-1}(2x)}$.
It's indeterminate form so I used L'Hospital's rule but I'm stuck at here;

$\lim_{x\to 0+}\ln(\sin^2(4x))^{\sin^{-1}(2x)}=\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{2\ln(\sin(4x))}{1/\sin^{-1}(2x)}=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{4(\sin^{-1}(2x))^2\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{\tan x} $

Could you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on the work you've done already. The classical way to use l'Hospital in forms with an exponent is to calculate the limit of the natural logarithm of the form, which changes the exponent into a factor.

Comment: Does $\sin^{-1}(2x)$ mean $\arcsin(2x)$?

Comment: @Alexander Geldhof Sorry for any confuse, I skipped some calculations. I used the fact that f(x)^g(x)=e^f(x)*g(x) and a*b=b*(1/a) and used  l'Hospital in second equality.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Yes it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}t\ln t = 0$ as follows:

You may write

$$\ln\left((\sin^2(4x))^{\sin^{-1}(2x)}\right) =\underbrace{\frac{\sin^{-1} (2x)}{2x}}_{\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\rightarrow}1}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{4x}{\sin 4x}}_{\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\rightarrow}1}\underbrace{\sin (4x)\ln (\sin 4x)}_{\stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\rightarrow}0}$$

It follows
$$\lim_{x\to 0+}(\sin^2(4x))^{\sin^{-1}(2x)}= e^0 = 1$$

Comment: The best way of course!

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't know that limit arcsinx/x =1.

Comment: @ScottLee : You are welcome. You can see this limit just by substituting $x= \sin t \Rightarrow \frac{t}{\sin t}$.

Comment: @user : Thanks user (gimusi) :-D

Comment: @trancelocation Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

We have that

- $\sin^2(4x)=16x^2+o(x^2)$
- $\sin^{-1}(2x)=2x+o(x^2)$

therefore

$${\sin^2(4x)}^{\sin^{-1}(2x)}=e^{(2x+o(x^2))\log(16x^2+o(x^2))}\to e^0=1$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! The 2 equations are obtained by maclaurin series right?

Comment: Yes of course exactly!

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

L'Hospital's rule is not the alpha and omega of limits computations!

It is very simple using *equivalents*:

We'll first determine the limit of the log:
$$\ln \Bigl(\bigl(\sin^2 4x\bigr)^{\arcsin 2x}\Bigr)=2\arcsin 2x\ln(\sin 4x).$$
Now, we have:

- $\arcsin 2x\sim_0 2x$;
- $\sin 4x\sim_0 4x$, so $\ln(\sin 4x)\sim_{0^+} \ln(4x)$.

Therefore
$\;2\arcsin 2x\ln(\sin 4x)\sim_{0^+} 4x\ln(4x)$, which tends to $0$ by a standard high-school limit. By continuity, the limit of the given expression is equal to $1$.